# How to update value of column after insert data into table

Tags: sql

I have a `TableA`, like as below:

```
ID | ColumnA | ColumnB | ColumnC |
1  | apple   | banana  | coconut |
2  | x       | y       | z       |
3  | a       | b       | c       |
```

now, I want to copy row has ID = 2 then insert into `tableA` and revise y -> y1.

I coded:

```
update TableA
set ColumnB  = 'y1'
where ID = insert into TableA 
            output ID
            select ColumnA , ColumnB , ColumnC 
            from TableA
            where ID = 2
```

Comment: [Why should I "tag my RDBMS"?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/388759/why-should-i-tag-my-rdbms)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not just use one query?

```
insert into TableA (ColumnA, ColumnB, ColumnC)
    select ColumnA , 'y1' , ColumnC 
    from TableA
    where ID = 2;
```